# How does JSX interact with an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

This is a question more so on logistics than code. How does JSX interact with HTML files? When would I use JSX versus HTML? For example, say I have the file `example.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <button id="button" onclick="example()">click me</button>
</body>

<script>
    function example() {
    var b = document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "clicked";
}
</script>

</html>
```

How do I recreate this button and its properties in JSX? Do I need to use HTML at all in this situation or does the use of JSX replace HTML?

Also apologies if this is an irrelevant question for Stackoverflow. If it is, where should I ask this question instead? Thanks.

Comment: read docs, search for tutorials, lots of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSX is an extension of JavaScript that supports embedding HTML elements.

There's an important distinction here: JSX is JavaScript, which is a programming language. HTML is a document format. You can't "run" HTML. But you can run JavaScript, and the JavaScript program can generate HTML.

The JSX file gets compiled into JavaScript that is run by the browser. Where you have HTML elements in the JSX, the JSX compiler generates calls to React to create those HTML elements and add them to the HTML DOM.

If you wanted to use JSX for this, you'd be writing a React application. But the application you write wouldn't look much like this HTML. Instead you'd use React components to create the button and change its label when you click it, and React will take care of generating the HTML for you.